# Geoserver TextSymbolizer rendering problem?

Tags: dictionary, mapping, styling, geoserver, labeling

I use geoserver 2.0.1, I used textsymbolizer to labeling features on the map. It is likely geoserver not support '' tag because event I try to change font-size, font-family or .. it deosn't effect. How can I do labeling on the feature with different style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you insert this into your `<rule>...</rule>` section, you should get something.

Just make sure that you provide the right property name (in the example blow: InfoMessage), which is the field that you want to display.

If the example below doesn't help, then please post your style, and describe what you're trying to achieve, so I can see what's going wrong.

```
      <TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>InfoMessage</ogc:PropertyName>
        </Label>
        <Font>
          <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-weight">Bold</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-size">14</CssParameter>
        </Font>
        <LabelPlacement>
          <PointPlacement>
            <AnchorPoint>
              <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
              <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
            </AnchorPoint>
            <Displacement>
              <DisplacementX>0</DisplacementX>
              <DisplacementY>-15</DisplacementY>
            </Displacement>
          </PointPlacement>
        </LabelPlacement>
        <Halo>
          <Radius>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </Radius>
          <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
          </Fill>
        </Halo>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </TextSymbolizer>
```

Comment: Make sure that Arial (or other font) is available on your machine. Later versions of GeoServer will provide you with a list of available fonts.

Comment: yes, I have have textsymbolizer similar to your. But when I try to change the font-size or font-family it doesn't effect. I use geoserver 2.0.1

Comment: Although i find it very unintuitive, it the order of the xml tags matters. Double-check the order of your label, font, etc sections if it's still not working.